# Symfony & Doctrine: Order Form Type By Choice Label

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form type in Symfony 2.8 that uses a `choice_label` option. This value is a function that applies some formatting on a parameter with the purpose to return the field `name` with any leading "The " strings move to the end (so "The Company Inc" becomes "Company Inc, The".

How can I order the `FormType` by the `choice_label` when this is not an entity field?

```
// \Form\Type\AdvertiserType.php
...
->add(
    'advertiser',
    'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Advertiser',
        'label' => 'Advertiser Account',
        'choice_label' => 'formattedName',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repo) {
            return $repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC')
            ;
        }
    )
)
...
```

I can't use `orderBy('a.formattedName', 'ASC')` in the query builder as this is a function name and not an entity field.

The advertiser entity has this additional function:

```
// Entity\Advertiser.php
...
public function getFormattedName() {
    if (substr($this->name, 0, 4) == 'The ') {
        return substr($this->name, 4) . ', The';
    } else {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
...
```

Thanks for nay help or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement sorting function in repository

```
public function getSortedList()
{
    $entities = $this->findAll();

    usort($entities, function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->getFormattedName(), $b->getFormattedName());
    });

    return $entities;
}
```

pass it to FormType in controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(AdvertiserType::class, $advertiser, array('repository' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Advertiser')));
```

and then change query_builder to choices

```
// \Form\Type\AdvertiserType.php
// before $builder->add
$repo = $options['repository'];
...
->add(
    'advertiser',
    'entity',
    array(
        ...
        'choices' => $repo->getSortedList(),
        }
    )
)
...

// and in configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) method
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Advertiser',
    'validation_groups' => array(),
    'repository' => null
));
```

Comment: That's great. Worked out of the box, thanks!! I just had to change `strcmp()` to `strnatcasecmp(str_replace("[", "0000000000", $a->getQueueName()), str_replace("[", "0000000000", $b->getQueueName()))` to ensure numbers are ordered first and that UTF8 characters like é are ordered within e (and not added at the end).